# Criando um CSV a partir de 3 tabelas CSV

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, dataset

Tenho duas tabelas CSV e preciso fazer um merge com as colunas incomuns nas duas tabelas criando um única tabela.

Contudo, quando escrevo o código, fica um tempo muito grande de processamento e não completa. Como eu poderia escrever de forma diferente o código abaixo?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file_path = "./exercise_data/"

data_a = pd.read_csv(
    file_path + "features.csv",
    delimiter="|", dtype=str
)
data_b = pd.read_csv(
    file_path + "historic_sales.csv",
    delimiter="|", dtype=str
)
data_c = pd.read_csv(
    file_path + "store_info.csv",
    delimiter=";", dtype=str
)

# Columns data_a ("features.csv")
data_b["Temperature"] = ""
data_b["Fuel_Price"] = ""
data_b["MarkDown1"] = ""
data_b["MarkDown2"] = ""
data_b["MarkDown3"] = ""
data_b["MarkDown4"] = ""
data_b["MarkDown5"] = ""
data_b["CPI"] = ""
data_b["Unemployment"] = ""

# Columns data_c ("store_info.csv")
data_b["Type"] = ""
data_b["Size"] = ""


for index, row in data_b.iterrows():
    store = row["Store"]
    date = row["Date"]
    try:
        df_feature = data_a.loc[
            (data_a["Store"] == store) & (data_a["Date"] == date)
        ].iloc[0]
        data_b.at[index, "Temperature"] = df_feature["Temperature"]
        data_b.at[index, "Fuel_Price"] = df_feature["Fuel_Price"]
        data_b.at[index, "MarkDown1"] = df_feature["MarkDown1"]
        data_b.at[index, "MarkDown2"] = df_feature["MarkDown2"]
        data_b.at[index, "MarkDown3"] = df_feature["MarkDown3"]
        data_b.at[index, "MarkDown4"] = df_feature["MarkDown4"]
        data_b.at[index, "MarkDown5"] = df_feature["MarkDown5"]
        data_b.at[index, "CPI"] = df_feature["CPI"]
        data_b.at[index, "Unemployment"] = df_feature["Unemployment"]
    except:
        pass
    try:
        df_info = data_c.loc[data_c["Store"] == store].iloc[0]
        data_b.at[index, "Type"] = df_info["Type"]
        data_b.at[index, "Size"] = df_info["Size"]
    except:
        pass


data_b.to_csv('a_and_c_to_b.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi direito você tem dois *dataframes* A e B e você quer criar um novo *dataframe* com as colunas de A e B, você pode fazer isso no pandas usando `pd.concat`

```
import pandas as pd

dataA = pd.read_csv(...)
dataB = pd.read_csv(...)

#Usamos axis = 1 para dizer pro pandas juntar os DF's nas colunas
dataC = pd.concat([dataA, dataB], axis=1)
```

Para mais informações da uma olhada [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)